# Em sistemas operativos qual a diferença entre operações I/O e operações E/S?

Tags: terminologia, sistema-operacional, sistemas-distribuídos

Estou com algumas dúvidas em distinguir estas duas operações, elas são parecidas mas penso que não o mesmo, apesar de ambas terem haver com entrada e saída de alguma "coisa".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nenhuma diferença. I/O é Input/Output. E/S é Entrada/Saída. Ou seja, é só uma questão de tradução.

Operações de IO é tudo o que o sistema operacional trata com dispositivos que não sejam o processador ou a memória.

Comment: Em vários artigos portugueses, vejo ambas as definições tanto E/S como I/O, daí a minha pergunta. Em que situações se deverá cada uma ? Será indiferente ?

Comment: @jorgesaraiva considero indiferente. Eu percebo que em Portugal há uma tendência maior do uso do termo traduzido, mas posso estar enganado. è mais uma questão linguística mesmo, tecnicamente não tem motivo para usar um ou outro.

Comment: assim fico mais esclarecido. Mas basicamente esta operações são feitas entre o S.O e os dispositivos I/O sob forma interrupções correcto ?

Comment: @jorgesaraiva isso mesmo.